# Validation Group

Tags: javascript, devexpress, validationgroup

Is it possible to get and control a validation group using javascript? I was able to validate `ASPxHtmlEditor` if empty or not, but i need to control the validation group. I'm using .net 2.0.

EDITS [04202011]

I need to make `ASPxHtmlEditor` a required field. I'm using an older version (10.1.6.0) of DevEx (can't update right now), but there is no validation settings for it. I used javascript to validate the editor

```
function validateEmptyEditor(html)
{
   html = html.replace('&nbsp;', '');
   html = html.replace('<br />', '');

   if (html.length < 1)
   {
      return false;
   }
   else
   {
      return true;
   }
}
```

I invoked the function in `LostFocus` of `ASPxHtmlEditor.ClientSideEvents` and is working properly. But my page uses validation group for saving. So I need to manipulate validation group when `validateEmptyEditor` is invoked. Is it possible to control validation group?

Comment: Hi, please give us more details about the task you need to accomplish.  We will try to help you.

Comment: Hi, please refer to my EDITS [04202011], thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your task properly, you would like to know, whether the controls residing in the ValidationGroup are passing validation or not.  If so, this can be done using the following js code:

```
var isValid = ASPxClientEdit.ValidateGroup("GroupName");
```

Does this help?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately `ASPxHtmlEditor` under the version stated above, does not support validation settings, so it will not be included when evaluating the validation group. Is it possible to assign value to the validation group to make it false?

Comment: But this is a helpful function, i could use this in some of my pages. Thanks :D

Comment: It is impossible to set the validation group result.  However, before posting data to the server, you can check both the HtmlEditor's value and ValidationGroup result.  If both are correct, you should allow to post the request to the server.  Otherwise - forbid.

Comment: Yeah I forgot that. I can use `e.ProcessOnServer = false;` right?